# How to pass 'Select All' parameter in SSRS report url?

Tags: url, reporting-services, parameters, ms-reports

I've been stuck with this problems for 2 days now and I don't know how to corner it.
Basicly, I'm building list of report URL's with provided parameters in URL so I can run them without selecting each checkbox. I've found the way how to select most of the values without problem, but sometimes I want to choose "(Select All)" option from dropdown, but I don't know how. What do I need to pass in parameter so that it would select all for rendering a report?

Do you have any suggestions?

for example,this works for me:
&Company=**xxxx**&Partner=**yyyy**&Name=**3**&rs:Command=Render

Answer (score 1):

Default the Parameter(s) to NULL in the RDL. Then you can simply call the report without specifying a value for the parameter and it will automatically pass NULL into the proc.

Then in your proc you will need to change your predicate (probably, although no code has been provided) to something like this:

```
Where (tablealias.Company  = @Company or @Company is NULL)
AND (tablealias.partner  = @Partner or @Partner is NULL)
etc
```

So taking company as an example, if you specify a value in the URL it will search for that value in the proc, if you don't it will return regardless of company.